# Need help regarding Dual boot

Tags: dual-boot

I just bought Asus zenbook 256gb ssd version. 
It has windows 10 pre-installed. I need to dual boot it with ubuntu.Are there any complications with it?

Comment: You need to install in UEFI boot mode.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI  and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi  What model Asus. Does it have proprietary video?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu) and [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)